# How to iterate over all values in a dictionary to adjust by 1 million using for loops

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator

```
sol = {"Uranus":[2750, 3000, 2880], "Mercury":[46, 70, 57], "Earth":[147, 152, 150], "Venus":[107, 109, 108], "Mars":[205, 249, 228], "Saturn":[1350, 1510, 1430], "Jupiter":[741, 817, 779], "Pluto":[4440, 7380, 5910], "Neptune":[4450, 4550, 4500]}
```

I am trying to take the above dictionary I have compiled using different amounts of measured distances, but I need to be able to find a way to take all values(which are in millions) and multiply each value by 1 million. I can iterate over the keys, but I am stuck trying to figure out how to iterate through the values for each key. Below is the code I am currently working on, albeit probably wrong. Thanks for the help.

```
MILLION = 1000000
length = len(sol[planet])
for planet in sol:
    for i in sol[planet]:
           i*Million           
print(sol)
```

Comment: You are multiplying, but it's not clear what you want to do that value. Are you trying to save it back to the original dictionary? Print it? Something else?

Comment: Good question Mark, I am trying to save it back to the original dictionary. I'm trying to add additional info onto the dictionary once its back, but I need it to stay in the dictionary format.

Comment: @AMC OP already mentioned `how to iterate through the values for each key.` and in previous comments, he mentioned his issue

Comment: @sahasrara62 _and in previous comments, he mentioned his issue_ Which comment?

Comment: @AMC Good question Mark, I am trying to save it back to the original dictionary. I'm trying to add additional info onto the dictionary once its back, but I need it to stay in the dictionary format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each value is a list, you can do the following.

```
for planet in sol:
    for i in range(len(sol[planet])):
        sol[planet][i] *= 1000000

print(sol)
```

This returns `{'Uranus': [2750000000, 3000000000, 2880000000], 'Mercury': [46000000, 70000000, 57000000], 'Earth': [147000000, 152000000, 150000000], 'Venus': [107000000, 109000000, 108000000], 'Mars': [205000000, 249000000, 228000000], 'Saturn': [1350000000, 1510000000, 1430000000], 'Jupiter': [741000000, 817000000, 779000000], 'Pluto': [4440000000, 7380000000, 5910000000], 'Neptune': [4450000000, 4550000000, 4500000000]}`, which seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a dictionary comprehension:

```
sol = { k : [d*1000000 for d in v] for k, v in sol.items() }
```

Output:

```
{
 'Uranus': [2750000000, 3000000000, 2880000000],
 'Mercury': [46000000, 70000000, 57000000],
 'Earth': [147000000, 152000000, 150000000],
 'Venus': [107000000, 109000000, 108000000],
 'Mars': [205000000, 249000000, 228000000],
 'Saturn': [1350000000, 1510000000, 1430000000],
 'Jupiter': [741000000, 817000000, 779000000],
 'Pluto': [4440000000, 7380000000, 5910000000],
 'Neptune': [4450000000, 4550000000, 4500000000]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Iterate over a copy of the dict items

```
from copy import deepcopy

for k, v in deepcopy(sol).items():
    sol[k] = [i * MILLION for i in v]
```